# Using Font Awesome in Google Autocomplete Pac-Input

Tags: css, google-maps

I am trying to use the Font Awesome Map Marker in a Google Autocomplete Input.  My goal is to have the Map Marker to the left of the placeholder text, be able to add a color to just the map marker, and to have it always present even when the user is typing.  So far I have tried:

`<span class="google-address-bar"><input #pacinput id="pac-input" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="&#xf041;  Enter Your Street Address">
</span>`

with :

`#pac-input {
    font-family: Fira-Sans, FontAwesome, Serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 400px;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}`

but with this solution I am unable to add color to just the Map Marker and since it is placeholder, it disappears once the input is dirty.  Has anyone accomplished this?

Comment: You can't mix fonts in a `placeholder`

Comment: I know, that is why I am seeking other solutions.

Comment: Use `<label>` for the Font  Auseome part? and then position it?

Comment: hmm, this could work, had not considered absolute positioning.

Comment: This works, but covers the text that the user inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `<label>` or `<i>` for the Font Awseome part and then position then icon over the `input`. Then all that is required is adjusting the padding.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.google-address-bar {
  position: relative;
}
.google-address-bar i.fa {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-left: .5em;
}
#pac-input {
  font-family: Fira-Sans, Serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class="google-address-bar"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
  <input #pacinput id="pac-input" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=" Enter Your Street Address">
</span>
```